# Oracle Scheduler proc doesn't complete before next start time

Tags: oracle, plsql, scheduler, oracle12c

I want to know what will happen if a scheduler takes more than hour to complete but the scheduler is configured to re-run for every hour. Would it create multiple running sessions or would it wait for the previous run to complete?

Answer (score 4):

It will wait.  I'll start this job every minute, but it takes 2 mins to run

```
SQL> create table t ( tag varchar2(10), d date);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure P is
  3  begin
  4    insert into t values ('start',sysdate);
  5    commit;
  6    dbms_lock.sleep(120);
  7    insert into t values ('end',sysdate);
  8    commit;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_scheduler.create_job (
  3      job_name        => 'JOB1',
  4      job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5      job_action      => 'begin p; end;',
  6      start_date      => systimestamp,
  7      repeat_interval => 'freq=minutely;bysecond=0;',
  8      enabled         => true);
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from t;

TAG        D
---------- -------------------
start      03/05/2018 22:47:00
end        03/05/2018 22:49:00
start      03/05/2018 22:49:00
```